# How to add custom Buy Now button on the product page of Magento

Tags: magento

I am not as good at coding. I am trying to add a custom button on the product detail page which acts as Add to cart and Buy Now as well. When clicking on this button it should add the product in cart and redirect to the checkout page. I am using Magento 1.8.1 and have a responsive theme.

Please, any one can help me to tell all the steps.

Answer (score 2):

app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Find this code

```
 <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
       <label for="qty"><?php //echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
```

comment both lines

```
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
       <!-- <label for="qty"><?php //echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php //echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php// echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" /> -->
        <?php endif; ?>
```

after end if insert this code

```
<input type="image" class="button btn-cart" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinurl('images/buy.png')?>" onclick="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl()?>">
```

final code look like this

```
 <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
       <!-- <label for="qty"><?php //echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php //echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php// echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />  -->
        <?php endif; ?>


  <input type="image" class="button btn-cart" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinurl('images/buy.png')?>" onclick="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl()?>">
```

add image in skin/frontend/package/theme/images/buy.png

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response. The code work fine but there is problem in loading image. Image does't display. I have tried .gif,.jpeg, .png as well.

Comment: My url is www.lycraze.com

Comment: I am able to display image on it now, but not able to modify size of image please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell me which file you are referring for above code. I do not see that code in addtocart.phtml.

Comment: add this in ur css
.button.btn-cart{width: 50px; height: 50px; }

Comment: i know u get ur answer pls accept this as a right answer

Comment: Ya sorry for delay response. Your suggestion helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly open app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Add below line into `<form>` Tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="buy_now" id="buy_now" value="" />
```

Put below button at anywhere where you want

```
<button type="button" onclick="jQuery('#buy_now').val('buy_now');productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="btn btn-block btn-express-buynow"><i class="cart-icon-white m-r-sm v-middle"></i>Buy Now</button>
```

Now open app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

Change the code as below instructions

Put below line in _goBack() function at very first

```
$buy_now = $this->getRequest()->getParam('buy_now');
```

FInd the line $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl); and replace this line as below code

```
if (!empty($buy_now)) {
    $this->_redirect('onepagecheckout'); // If you are using onepagecheckout or use this $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/')
}else{
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
}
```

Code Taken from this [link](http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-add-buynow-button-on-product.html)